# RuntimeException y IllegalStateException al crear recordatorios con AlarmManager y Room

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que entre muchas funciones programa recordatorios (notificaciones y/o alarmas) utilizando AlarmManager, dado que el usuario puede crear una gran cantidad de recordatorios decidí que cuando el usuario agregue un recordatorio no se programe con AlarmManager sino que se agregue a una base de datos SQLite y se programe el día en el que debería sonar, he utilizado esto:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction("UNICO");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.cancel(pendingIntent);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cHoraActivacion.getTimeInMillis(), (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), pendingIntent);
```

Esto hará que "UNICO" se active todos los días a las 00:00 hrs para activar con AlarmManager los recordatorios del día:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (appDataBase == null){
        appDataBase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDataBase.class, Constant.DB_NAME)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
    }

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action != null && context != null) {
        if("UNICO".equals(action)) {
            activarDespertadorDelDia(context);
            activarAvisosDeClasesDelDia(context, appDataBase);
            activarRecordatoriosAgendaDelDia(context, appDataBase);
        }
```

Esto es activarRecorodatoriosAgendaDelDia:

```
static void activarRecordatoriosAgendaDelDia(Context context, AppDataBase appDataBase){
    long idSemestreActual = MisAjustes.getSemestreActual(context);
    String horaActual = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
    List<Integer> idsRecordatoriosHoy = appDataBase.recordatorioDao().listaIdsRecordatoiosDelDia(idSemestreActual, fechaHoyFormatoSQL(), horaActual);
    for (int i = 0; i < idsRecordatoriosHoy.size(); i++){
        int idRecordatorio = idsRecordatoriosHoy.get(i);
        String[] horaRecordatorio = appDataBase.recordatorioDao().obtenerHoraRecordatorio(idRecordatorio).split(":");
        int horaR = Integer.parseInt(horaRecordatorio[0]);
        int minutoR = Integer.parseInt(horaRecordatorio[1]);
        Calendar cFechaDeRecordatorio = Calendar.getInstance();
        cFechaDeRecordatorio.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, horaR);
        cFechaDeRecordatorio.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutoR);
        cFechaDeRecordatorio.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cFechaDeRecordatorio.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        if (cFechaDeRecordatorio.after(Calendar.getInstance()))
            NotificationScheduler.setRecordatorioAgenda(context, idRecordatorio, cFechaDeRecordatorio);
    }
}
```

Esto es listaIdsRecordatoriosDelDia:

```
@Query("SELECT Recordatorio._id FROM Recordatorio\n" +
        "INNER JOIN Evento ON Recordatorio.id_evento_rc=Evento._id\n" +
        "INNER JOIN Semestre ON Evento.id_semestre_ev=Semestre._id\n" +
        "WHERE Semestre._id=:idSemestre\n" +
        "AND Recordatorio.fecha = :fechaHoy\n" +
        "AND Recordatorio.hora>=:hora\n" +
        "ORDER BY Recordatorio.hora")
List<Integer> listaIdsRecordatoiosDelDia(long idSemestre, String fechaHoy, String hora);
```

En mi Samsung J2 con Android 8.1 funciona bien, pero esto es lo que me aparece en PlayConsole:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4452)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600 (ActivityThread.java:301)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2159)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8506)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade (RoomOpenHelper.java:117)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:177)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:489)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:387)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:145)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction (RoomDatabase.java:476)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction (RoomDatabase.java:281)
  at com.nombre.paquete.crud.RecordatorioDao_Impl.listaIdsRecordatoiosDelDia (RecordatorioDao_Impl.java:270)
  at com.nombre.paquete.AlarmReceiver.activarRecordatoriosAgendaDelDia (AlarmReceiver.java:360)
  at com.nombre.paquete.AlarmReceiver.onReceive (AlarmReceiver.java:65)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4443)
```

Apenas actualice ayer y ya le ha pasado a 5 teléfonos diferentes: Samsung Galaxy A50, Samsung Galaxy S10e, Samsung Galaxy M01s, Samsung Galaxy A31, LGE QStylus, quiero aclarar que `activarRecordatoriosAgendaDelDia` también se llama al reiniciar el teléfono y le ha pasado a 2 usuarios.

Por lo que veo en PlayConsole el error está en esta linea 360 que es esta:

```
List<Integer> idsRecordatoriosHoy = appDataBase.recordatorioDao().listaIdsRecordatoiosDelDia(idSemestreActual, fechaHoyFormatoSQL(), horaActual);
```

Pero no logro entender que puede estar pasando espero que me puedan orientar

**EDITADO**

Estas son las tablas de la consulta realizada
[image: Diagrama de tablas]

Esto es fechaHoyFormatoSQL:

```
static String fechaHoyFormatoSQL(){
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Comment: El problema esta en el método ``listaIdsRecordatoiosDelDia`` . Revisa si la consulta esta bien escrita. Te serviría leer esto:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169127/what-is-illegalstateexception

Comment: Lo acabo de analizar, he agregado un diagrama de mis tablas, la consulta está bien escrita y tampoco considero que haya errores lógicos, como lo mencioné estuve haciendo pruebas de diversos tipos durante más de 1 semana y en mi dispositivo nunca falló estoy muy confundido